# Kivy: Unable to load GStreamer on OSX

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, kivy, gstreamer

I followed the instruction on https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-osx.html#using-pip

If run kivy/examples/demo/kivycatalog/main.py
I however get the error:

```
   File "/Users/sonium/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/uix/video.py", line 171, in _do_video_load
     self._video = CoreVideo(filename=filename, **self.options)
   File "/Users/sonium/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/core/video/video_gstplayer.py", line 56, in __init__
     super(VideoGstplayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/Users/sonium/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/core/video/__init__.py", line 83, in __init__
     self.filename = kwargs.get('filename')
   File "/Users/sonium/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/core/video/__init__.py", line 115, in <lambda>
     lambda self, x: self._set_filename(x),
   File "/Users/sonium/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/core/video/__init__.py", line 112, in _set_filename
     self.load()
   File "/Users/sonium/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/core/video/video_gstplayer.py", line 68, in load
     self.player.load()
   File "kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.pyx", line 233, in kivy.lib.gstplayer._gstplayer.GstPlayer.load (/private/var/folders/vq/y67f0ypn5857c1k0xh0qmhvr0000gn/T/pip-build-iolf02v6/kivy/kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.c:2791)
 kivy.lib.gstplayer._gstplayer.GstPlayerException: Unable to create a playbin
```

edit:
the problem was partly fixed with 'brew install gst-python' but it seems to need gst-ffmpeg which has been renamed to gst-libav. Playing a video still fails with:

```
WARNING] [VideoGstplayer] b"No decoder available for type 'video/x-matroska'."
[ERROR  ] [VideoGstplayer] b'Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in.'
[ERROR  ] [VideoGstplayer] b'GStreamer encountered a general stream error.'
```

Comment: I would first try the good old gst-launch-1.0 test eg run from shell: `gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! autovideosink` if you have correctly installed gstreamer.. I dont know how kivy installs/uses gstreamer ..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to install a couple of gstreamer plugins... try this:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/LJrQGiN773A

Execute the following command with homebrew:

```
brew install gstreamer gst-plugins-base gst-plugins-good gst-plugins-bad gst-plugins-ugly gst-ffmpeg010
```